# Here's a clean and easy visual riddle

Tags: riddle, visual

The images below can be connected by a single word.

[image: A Microfiber lens cleaning cloth]

[image: A pig]

[image: A pretty back]

[image: A big pink brain]

[image: A generic car]

[image: A chopping board]

[image: A mouth]

[image: The white rabbit]

What is the word and what are the connections?

Comment: You did it again :)

Comment: @A.D. I think I've probably done 10+ now...  or there abouts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word is

> **WASH**

Explanation:

> 1. **WASH**CLOTH
> 2. HOG**WASH**
> 3. BACK**WASH**
> 4. BRAIN**WASH**
> 5. CAR**WASH**
> 6. **WASH**BOARD
> 7. MOUTH**WASH**
> 8. WHITE**WASH**  (the White Rabbit)

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't realise there were two new answers!  You got it first. +1 and accepted

Answer (score 3):

The answer is:

> Wash

[image]

> Washcloth

[image]

> [Pig wash](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Pig%20Wash) OP: I was actually thinking of "Hogwash"

[image]

> [Body wash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shower_gel) OP: I was actually thinking of "Backwash" but yours works

[image]

> [Brain wash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainwashing)

[image]

> [Car wash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car_wash)

[image]

> [washboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washboard_(laundry))

[image]

> [mouthwash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouthwash)

[image]

> [White Rabbit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI3jb.png)
>  A watch ---> Wash OP: I was actually thinking of "Whitewash"

Here's a clean and easy visual riddle:

> White is the colour of cleanness and you get clean by washing your body

Comment: I'm impressed that you got it with so few of the connections that I had in mind.  I'll add a few 'OP:' edits to your answer if you don't mind.

Comment: It's Okay go ahead :)

Comment: Sorry.  I didn't realise that someone had posted this answer just before you.  +1 but I had to give it to @Rubio

Comment: Yeah he beat me to it because of all the links I added, Thanks for the up vote though...

Comment: Yeah.  It's probably not best practice but I tend to answer quickly with basic explanations and then edit to add the bells and whistles afterwards.